# Angular/Node - Property 'text' does not exist on type '{} | Response'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I had a simple component in my angular project till I recently made some changes with my package.json, downgraded from 4.2.4 to 4.1.3, did npm install then returned back to 4.2.4... and now I'm getting this error when building the project:

> $ ng build
>   Your global Angular CLI version (1.5.0) is greater than your local
>   version (1.4.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
>   Date: 2018-02-22T11:38:57.826Z
>   Hash: 60271d03b90ff65e3d81
>   Time: 3114ms
>   chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
>   chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 303 bytes [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 323 bytes {inline} [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 11.3 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
>
> ERROR in C:/workspace/DataFab/dev/ResourcesManagement/web/ResourceManagerWebClient/src/app/components/about/about.component.ts (16,49): Property 'text' does not exist on type '{} | Response'.
>     Property 'text' does not exist on type '{}'.

the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ResourcesService } from '../../services/resources.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  version;
  constructor(private resourcesService: ResourcesService) { 
this.version = resourcesService.getVersion()
    .subscribe( data => this.version = data.text(), error => console.log(error) ).toString();
  }
```

How can revert back? 
Is it related to angular version? npm version?

I updated npm to the latest version but it didnt help:

> $ npm -v
>   5.6.0

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the getVersion code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.version = resourcesService.getVersion()
.subscribe( data => this.version = data.text(), error => console.log(error) ).toString(); }
```

It's related just to typing.

Just add type :any to data:

```
this.version = resourcesService.getVersion()
.subscribe( data:any => this.version = data.text(), error => console.log(error) ).toString();
```

}

You also may use Interfaces to typing your responses, like:

```
export interface ResponseI {
    text: string;
    something: any;
}
```

And the use it in your service:

```
return this.http.get<ResponseI>(...);
```

In that case you should not define data as any type and may just use it like in your example:

```
this.version = resourcesService.getVersion()
.subscribe( data => this.version = data.text(), error => console.log(error) ).toString();
```

}

And one more. Better code would be:

```
resourcesService.getVersion()
    .subscribe( data:any => this.version = data.text(), error => 
       console.log(error) );
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I used this code at the end: 
resourcesService.getVersion()
        .subscribe( (data:Response) => this.version = data.text(), 
            error => console.log(error) );
weird that it did work without it before!

Comment: I have another issue if you can help pls (or shall I open a new thread?)
I have this code in my service:
this.getUser().subscribe( data => this.user = data.text(), error => console.log(error) );

that is calling a rest api to get the logged-in user. If I'm navigating within my router this code works, if I refresh the page manually it doesn't!

I mean, the data.text() include the correct user, bu the variable this.user is undefined!

Comment: @zbeedatm it is probably good to open another thread for this issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931105/observable-is-not-saving-the-data-when-refreshing-the-page-manually