# Observable is not saving the data when refreshing the page manually

Tags: angular, observable

I have this code in my service constructor:

```
this.getUser().subscribe( data => this.user = data.text(), error => console.log(error) );
```

When navigating in my app with router links (from menu) this code works, but when refreshing the page manually... data.text() includes the logged-in user (I can see it if I print it to console) but this.user variable is not saving it and it remains "undefined"!

I tried so far using a setTimeout or a BehaviorSubject but with no luck:

```
private _subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
subject$ = this._subject.asObservable();
this.getUser().subscribe( data => 
        //setTimeout(() => { this.user = data.text() }, 1000),
          this.user = this._subject.next(data),
                error => console.log(error) );
```

## Update:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ResourcesService } from './services/resources.service';
import { PrivilegeService } from './services/privilege.service';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
user: string;
constructor(
        private resourcesService: ResourcesService,
        private privilegeService: PrivilegeService
        ) { 

    if (Config.PROD_MODE)
        resourcesService.getUser().subscribe( data => {
            this.user = data.text(); 
            resourcesService.user = data.text();
        }, error => {console.log(error);
```

resource.service.ts :

```
  constructor(public http: Http){ 
  this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' });
  this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers});}


/**
 * Get current user
 */
getUser(){
    let url = this.url + "user";  

    return this.http.get(url)
        //.catch( (error: any) => { console.log(error); return Observable.empty<Response>();} );
        .catch( (error: any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server Error - could not get user') );
}
```

privilege.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class PrivilegeService extends ResourcesService {
constructor(public http: Http){ 

  super(http);

  this.user = '';
```

resource-list.component:

```
public constructor(private resourcesService: ResourcesService,
                    private privilegeService: PrivilegeService, 
                    private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    if (Utils.isEmpty(this.resourcesService.user)){
        this.resourcesService.getUser().subscribe( data => {
            this.resourcesService.user = data.text();
            this.callGetResources();
        }, error => console.log(error) );
    }
}
```

I tried moving the call of get resources inside the observable block now I'm getting:

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
>       at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.es5.js:2610)
>       at AsyncPipe.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (common.es5.js:2755)

I realized that the call to getResources() is performed before setting the user variable of resources.service:

1. in app.component the call to getUser() is performed, but data is still not ready. while debuging I can see data as follow:

> message
>   :
>   "Unexpected end of input"
>   stack
>   :
>   "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input↵    at new AppComponent (http://localhost:8080/DataFabResourceManager/dist/main.bundle.js:247:9)↵

2. then the call to getResources() is performed from the resources-list page (the one I'm standing on when refreshing). But the user is still undefined at this point
3. back to app.component, now the data is ready and the user variable of resource service is sat (but too late):

> 200
>   statusText
>   :
>   "OK"
>   type
>   :
>   2
>   url
>   :
>   "http://localhost:8080/DataFabResourceManager/management/user"
>   _body
>   :
>   "regressiontester_db"
>   **proto**

Comment: Can you import `ChangeDetectorRef` from `@angular/core` and call `detectChanges()` on it after you assign a value to `this.user`? Does it work then? If so, the problem likely lies in the way you have your async calls structured; there is a conflict with the lifecycle of Angular change detection, so when you assign a value it is not being recognized.

Comment: when is your code called though?

Comment: @Lansana, detectChanges() didnt work: resourcesService.getUser().subscribe( data => {
                this.user = data.text(); 
                resourcesService.user = data.text();
                detectRef.markForCheck();
                detectRef.detectChanges();
            }, error => {console.log(error); window.location.href = "../Login.html";} );
            }, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

Try to do following:

in your service create function which would return observable:

```
getUser() {
    return http.get('here your rest api link to back-end');
}
```

And then call that method from your component, for example from ngOnInit() method. (You may follow by oficial guide from angular.io ):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUser().subscribe('here your subscribe logic'); 
}
```

Also provide HttpClient to your service as constructor param.
And then provide your service into component via constructor as well.

Helpful links:

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-pattern

http:
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

Comment: Hi @Pavel, this is what I have actually!
BTW, I tried what Lansana wrote in his comment (to use detectChanges() method) but it didn't make any different.
I need to find out why it's working when using the router when navigating and not working on refreshing the browser, mostly it's timing issue

Comment: @zbeedatm hi, may you please update your question with component and service code?

Comment: @zbeedatm hi, did you try to use ngOnInit() method in your component code? with calling your service there ?

Comment: moving the call to ngOnInit() didn't help as well :~

Comment: Please see my "Update 2" section. now it makes sense and I know what is the root cause, but the solution that I did is causing an exception